# Validations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have designed a very simple web application which associates authors, books and ratings.

In each of the respective models

```
Author
has_many :books

Book
belongs_to :author
has_many :reviews

Review
belongs_to :book
```

Model attributes

```
Author : title, fname, lname, DOB
Book : ISBN,  title, publish_date, pages
Review : rating(1-5), description
```

I am wondering if I completely validate all of these attributes to my liking in the models, 1 attribute for example

```
validates :ISBN, :only_integer => true, length: { is: 13 }
```

do I need to worry about validations for data elsewhere?

I know that validations for the model run on the server side so there may need to be some validation on the client side (in JS). I am trying to ensure that there are no flaws when it comes to asserting data correctness.

Comment: Where else would you validate them? They have to be valid in the model to save to the database. You could constrain the database for a number of validations (type, size, presence, permitted values, etc.) but not clear what that buys you except duplication of effort.

Comment: @dbugger it buys you an actual guarentee that the inserted data cannot violate the constraints.

Comment: @max true -- just have to decide if it is worth the effort for a particular application or even model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is so often the case: it depends.

In a simple Rails application, all models will be updated through a view request to a controller which in turn fills in the `params` into the models, then tries to `save` the model and any validation errors that occur are rendered back to the server.
In that scenario, all your code will have to do is to react to failed calls to `#save` but you can sleep soundly knowing that everything in your database is how it is supposed to be.

In more complex applications, putting all the validation logic into your model might not work as well anymore: every call to `#save` will have to run through all the validation logic, slowing things down, and different parts of your application might have different requirements to the input parameters.

In that scenario there are many ways to go about it. Form objects with validations specific to the forms they represent are a very common solution. These form models then distribute their input among one or more underlying ActiveRecord models.

But the Rails way is to take these one step at a time and avoid premature optimization. For the foreseeable future, putting your validation into your model will be enough to guarantee consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think because of the fact the web app is relatively small and not going to be deployed anywhere that I needn't worry. However, I will definitely keep these notes in mind when I have to deploy a project to the web. After all, that's why we have testing :)

Answer (score 2):

> do I need to worry about validations for data elsewhere?

#### Yes you do.

Application level validations are [still prone to race conditions](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations).

[image: Courtesy of Thoughtbot]

For things that should be unique like for example ISBN numbers database constraints are vital if uniqueness is to be guarenteed. Other areas where this can cause issues are when you have a limit on the count of an association.

While validations prevent most errors they are not a replacement for database constraints to ensure the correctness of data. Both are needed if correctness is important.

Comment: Yeah, this is also an important note as I can see. Thanks a lot for the heads up..

Comment: Another thing to bear in mind is that your validations just enforces the correctness when data is inserted through Rails - if you're using something like a import script you can still end up with invalid data.